# How to prevent requests to server when loading properties that are already in applet jar file?

Tags: java, properties, jar, applet

I maintain an applet that helps users to upload photos to our service. The applet `jar` file has a few `.properties` files:

```
>> jar -tf applet.jar | grep prop
res/messages.properties
res/messages_ca.properties
res/messages_es.properties
...
```

These are loaded during applet initialization.

```
messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("res.messages");
```

This call however generates 4 to 5 requests to the server looking for files that aren't in the `jar` file, before falling back on to the `.properties` file included in the `.jar`.

From the server error log:

```
[error] File does not exist: /photos/res/messages.class
[error] File does not exist: /photos/res/messages_en.class
[error] File does not exist: /photos/res/messages_en.properties
[error] File does not exist: /photos/res/messages_en_US.class
[error] File does not exist: /photos/res/messages_en_US.properties
```

The documentation for [ResourceManager.getBundle](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) explains that this is the way it is done:

> *getBundle then iterates over the candidate bundle names to find the first one for which it can instantiate an actual resource bundle. For each candidate bundle name, it attempts to create a resource bundle:*
>
> - *First, it attempts to load a class using the candidate bundle name. If such a class can be found and loaded using the specified class loader, is assignment compatible with ResourceBundle, is accessible from ResourceBundle, and can be instantiated, getBundle creates a new instance of this class and uses it as the result resource bundle.*
> - *Otherwise, getBundle attempts to locate a property resource file. It generates a path name from the candidate bundle name by replacing all "." characters with "/" and appending the string ".properties". It attempts to find a "resource" with this name using ClassLoader.getResource.*

I am sure there are good reasons for doing it this way, but in my case it seems wasteful to me that there should be five failed requests for files which are known to be non-existent on the server.

Is there any way to teach the applet to look for these files in the `.jar` file only?

Note: I am not a Java programmer, so if there is a better way to load properties than `ResourceManager.getBundle`, please let me know.

Comment: What is your minimum Java version?

Comment: 1.4 and above is what we need to support. Does your answer depend on this information? Please reply anyway. If your solution is not valid for older versions, it would still be useful, if only to add to the list of reasons why we should stop supporting 1.4 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java 1.6 introduced the [ResourceBundle.Control](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) class, which might have offered some help if you weren't supporting Java 1.4. As you are, it isn't rocket science to write your own bundle manager.

This demo code restricts bundle loading to properties files in a given set of languages:

```
public class CustomManager {
  private static final Map BUNDLES = new HashMap();

  public static ResourceBundle getBundle(String name, Set languages) {
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    if (languages.contains(locale.getLanguage())) {
      name = name + "_" + locale.getLanguage();
    }
    synchronized (BUNDLES) {
      ResourceBundle bundle = (ResourceBundle) BUNDLES.get(name);
      if (bundle == null) {
        ClassLoader loader = getContextClassLoader();
        bundle = loadBundle(loader, name.replace('.', '/') + ".properties");
        BUNDLES.put(name, BUNDLES);
      }
      return bundle;
    }
  }

  private static ClassLoader getContextClassLoader() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() != null ? Thread
        .currentThread().getContextClassLoader() : CustomManager.class
        .getClassLoader() != null ? CustomManager.class.getClassLoader()
        : ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
  }

  private static ResourceBundle loadBundle(ClassLoader loader, String res) {
    try { InputStream in = loader.getResourceAsStream(res);
      try { return new PropertyResourceBundle(in);
      } finally { in.close(); }
    } catch (IOException e) { throw new IllegalStateException(e.toString()); }
  }
}
```

This code simulates a call to retrieve strings for the Spanish/Spain locale:

```
Set languages = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "es", "ca" }));
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("es", "ES"));
ResourceBundle bundle = CustomManager.getBundle("l10n.res.foo", languages);
System.out.println(bundle.getString("bar"));
```

Since the set of languages is `es` and `ca` and `CustomManager` supports only languages (not country codes or variants) only the following files could be loaded:

```
l10n/res/foo.properties
l10n/res/foo_es.properties
l10n/res/foo_ca.properties
```

How sophisticated you want to get with [Locale](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) and [ClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) support, and where you want to manage your language list, is up to you.

Caveat: I don't *think* I violated any security restrictions with the implementation, but I only tested the code in a desktop app.

Comment: @McDowell: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I will try this approach.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, a little improvement would be:   if (languages.contains(locale.getLanguage())) name = name + "_" + locale.getLanguage();
else if (languages.contains(locale.toString())) name = name + "_" + locale.toString();

Comment: Note that there is a problem with this solution if you are expecting your applets to work with IcedTea-Web plugin, this won't work for Java code initiated from a JavaScript call (LiveConnect) as `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` won't return your applet class loader, but one class loader unable to load your resources. My advice, stick to the standard `java.util.ResourceBundle#getBundle` and just disable `codebase_lookup` to prevent calls to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `codebase_lookup` attribute to `false` in your `<applet>` tag configuration and your applet won't do any additional calls to the server for resources (e.g. i18n resource bundles).

```
<applet codebase_lookup="false" ...
```

More details on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/special_attributes.html#codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Jaime Hablutzel solution works fine.
It's a pity, that I still don't have enough reputation to vote it up.

Setting codebase_lookup to false when you instanciate the applet tells the classloader precisely that the applet is deployed with all the needed classes and resources within the jar files and to avoid the unnecessary codebase lookup.